# LIKE '[!a-z]%' not work

Tags: php, mysql

I create a filter and i have a "#" link.
I would like to have all the results except with letters. How to do that ?
When i do that :

```
$as = "a"; // "a" link text
... LIKE '$a%'
```

return all matches which starts with "a" but when i do that :

```
... LIKE '[!a-z]%'
// or
... NOT LIKE '[a-z]%'
```

It not work.
It should return the results without the first letters A to Z but It nothing in return.

Comment: Use `REGEXP` instead of `LIKE` when using regular expressions. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: Updated, a typo on my behalf.

Comment: `[!a-z]` is a single lowercase alpha character, or an exclamation mark. I don't think that is the regex you want either. I think `REGEXP '^[^A-Za-z]'` is what you want. That says the start of the string is not an alpha character.

Comment: thanks, it work perfectly

Comment: You should do an explain on these queries. In all likelihood they will not use an index which will lead to very poor performance.  Conversely, using LIKE or NOT LIKE can use an index so long as you to don't use `LIKE '%something%'`

Comment: vdd: i use LIKE for filter by one letter when i click on a link "a" for exemple. i will never use '%xxx%' in this situation because i need only one letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `like` support regular expressions, use [regexp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) instead.

`WHERE col_name REGEXP '[^a-z].*'`

`WHERE col_name NOT REGEXP '[a-z].*'`